# neo4j 2.1 not creating node but running successfully

Tags: java, neo4j, debian

I'am using debian distribution.I write a code in windows but I have no error and I create a database.Despite I prepare libraries in Debian, my database is not created and data is not added and in java program there was no error.

My Database Path.

```
dbPath=/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
```

I guess error occurs about database proporties.
I have 2 different proporties so I don't know how can I set this settings.

1. `-etc/neo4j`
2. `-/var/lib/neo4j/conf`

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties` file that typically begins like

```
################################################################
# Neo4j configuration
#
################################################################

#***************************************************************
# Server configuration
#***************************************************************

# location of the database directory 
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db
...
...
```

Where database path is relative.
If you want to have an absolute path, you should have this line:

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db
```